# Maximizing efficiency of this while loop

Tags: javascript, optimization, while-loop

I have a while loop that is supposed to randomly plant numberOfTruth true values in a 2 dimensional. I am only to change them if they are not true already, and only do so for numberOfTruths times:

```
function truthfulArray(maxY, maxX, numberOfTruths, array) {
  var x;
  var y;
  var counter = 0;

  while (counter < numberOfTruths) {
    x = generateRandomNumber(maxX);
    y = generateRandomNumber(maxY);

    if (!array[x][y]) {
      array[x][y] = true;
      counter++;
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

I could see the issue with its optimization in relation to the size of 2 dimensional array and as the numberOfTruths approaches the product of maxY and maxX it would waste alot of resources to complete the task. I was wondering what tweaks I can make to the function to make it more efficient. Thanks in advance!

*** `generateRandomNumber(max)` is a simple function that returns a random number from 0 to the max value entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Bergi's comment, here's one optimization. It assumes the array is empty to begin with (or rather, it doesn't care and just overwrites things).

It's slower when the fill factor (`N / (X * Y)`) is low (testing with X = Y = 500), but seems to win out over the original implementation at about 40%, and is decisively faster (like 3x) at 80%. (You might want to use that as a heuristic.)

The general idea is that we first fill random rows from the rows' start, then spread out each row using Fisher-Yates shuffle. I've transposed the `y` and `x` compared to the original, because that's just how I'm used to dealing with 2D arrays. :D

```
function shuffle(array) {  // h/t https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}

function truthfulArrayFillRows(maxY, maxX, numberOfTruths, array) {
  var nLeft = numberOfTruths;
  var nSeededPerRow = new Array(maxY).fill(0);

  // Seed rows randomly with trues starting from the left
  while(nLeft > 0) {
    var y = generateRandomNumber(maxY);
    var x = nSeededPerRow[y];
    if(x < maxX) {
        array[y][x] = true;
        nLeft --;
        nSeededPerRow[y] ++;
    }
  }

  // Shuffle the rows we seeded
  for(var y = 0; y < maxY; y++) {
    if(nSeededPerRow[y] > 0) {
        shuffle(array[y]);
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomly selecting `numberOfTruth` many positions of all possible positions, you could randomly select `numberOfTruth` many of only the valid positions. To do that, you would have to find those positions first.

```
function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}

function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var results = [];
    while (myArray.length) {
        results.push(myArray.splice(0, chunk_size));
    }    
    return results;
}

function flatten(array) {
  var flattened=[];
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; ++i) {
      var current = array[i];
      for (var j=0; j<current.length; ++j)
          flattened.push(current[j]);
  }
  return flattened;
}

function truthfulArray(maxY, maxX, numberOfTruths, array){
  var flatArray = flatten(array);
  var validPositions = flatArray.map(function(e, i){if(!e) return i});
  var randomPositions = shuffle(validPositions).slice(0, numberOfTruths);

  randomPositions.forEach(function(i){flatArray[i] = true;});

  return chunkArray(flatArray, maxY);
}


var maxX = 20, maxY = 30;
var array = Array(maxX).fill(Array(maxY).fill(false));
truthfulArray(maxY, maxX, 40, array);
```

If this approach is more efficient depends on your data. If there are many valid positions to choose from, your code should be totally fine and efficient. The more `true`s there are in the array the less likely it is that your code (randomly) hits them. In that case the approach I described will be more efficient.
I hope you find that helpful.